# Bounded Type Parameters casting issue

Tags: java, generics

I have a java interface like this

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {
  public <V extends T> V get(String key, Bundle bundle);
}
```

please note the `<V extends T>` type parameter of the method.

Then I have a class `MyFoo implements MyInterface`

```
class MyFoo implements MyInterface<Object> { // Object because can be any type

  @Override public <V> V get(String key, Bundle bundle) {
    return new Other();
  }
}
```

So when I now have a class like this:

```
class Bar {
   public Other other;

   public Other setOther(Other other);
}
```

Then I want to take `MyFoo` to set `Other` in a `Bar` instance:

```
MyFoo foo = new MyFoo();
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.other = foo.get();
```

This works perfectly. Type can be determined by java generics. No additional cast is needed.

However, if I want to use `bar.setOther()` then the type can not be determined:

```
MyFoo foo = new MyFoo();
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.setOther(foo.get()); // Fails
```

Then I get the following compile error:

> error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Other

I don't understand why this doesn't work for the `bar.setOther( foo.get() )` method but works when accessing the field directly `bar.other = foo.get()`

Any idea how to solve that without adding an extra cast like `bar.setOther( (Other) foo.get() )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an assignment, the Java compiler knows what return type to use for the method by looking at the type that it is being assigned to. So to answer your question

> Any idea how to solve that without adding an extra cast like
>   `bar.setOther( (Other) foo.get() )` ?

This is a way in which you can do that:

```
Other value = foo.get();
bar.setOther(value);
```

There is another way, which looks worse but still doesn't have a cast:

```
bar.setOther(foo.<Other>get());
```

And a third alternative: switch to Java 8; in Java 8 you can just do `bar.setOther(foo.get());`.

For Java 7, the rules for this type inference are specified in [JLS section 15.12.2.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.8):

> If any of the method's type arguments were not inferred from the types
>   of the actual arguments, they are now inferred as follows.
>
> If the **method result** occurs in a context where it will be subject to
>   **assignment** conversion (§5.2) to a type S, then [...]

A method result is subject to assignment conversion if it is used in an assignment expression.

> - Otherwise, the unresolved type arguments are inferred by invoking the
>     procedure described in this section under the assumption that the
>     method result was assigned to a variable of type `Object`.

If the unresolved type argument is used in a method whose result is not used in an assignment expression, then the type argument is interpreted as if the method result was assigned to a variable of type `Object`. So this means in this case that if the result of the `get()` method is not assigned to a variable, then the return type of the `get()` method is taken to be `Object`.

Comment: Yeah, that's a kind of workaround. So the compiler can't look at the type parameter of `setOther()`? Sounds weird ...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'll dig up the JLS section but I guess it has to do with the fact that a method can be overloaded for many parameter types, and the JLS didn't want to let overloaded method selection and concrete type selection for generic types interfere with each other.

Comment: overloading methods ... sounds plausible

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt This sounds like a plausible explanation, thank you!